# IF statement using find, otherwise use previous cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to automate data from a generated report, however can't get my IF statement to refer to the previous cell. The first part of the formula is fine.

`IF(FIND("L3:",A2),MID(A2,9,4),F1)`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGcUv.jpg]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `FIND` in `NOT(ISERROR(...))` to return `MID(A2,9,4)` when the text is found, and when it's not found (i.e. when `FIND` returns a `#VALUE` error as in your screenshot), return the previous cell.

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("L3:",A2))),MID(A2,9,4),F1)
```

*EDIT:*

If brevity is your thing, omit the `NOT` and flip the 2nd and 3rd arguments of `IF`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("L3:",A2)),F1,MID(A2,9,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(AND(LEN(A2)>1,FIND("L3:",A2&"L3:")=1),MID(A2,9,4),F1)
```

Find is proabably causing an error when L3: does not exist.  By appending the L3: to the end of the list you ensure it is found.  You just need to verify that its in the starting position.  However you also want to make sure the cell A2 is not empty so you need to have the length of the cell greater than 1 at the same time.